# Python - loop through list in specific order

Tags: python, oracle, loops, padding

I have a list defined as:

```
pad = [unhexlify('00' * (16-j) + ('%02d' % j) * j) for j in range(1, 17)]
```

This constructs a pad list for a padding oracle attack. Due to how this attack works I need to cycle through elements 2-16, then if I don't get a hit go back and try the 1st element. Here is the loop:

```
for padsel in pad:  #increment pad
    print(str(hexlify(padsel)) +  "- selected pad")
    for i in range(256):    #increment guess
        g = unhexlify("000000000000000000000000000000" + "{:02x}".format(i)) 
        print(str(hexlify(g)) + "- guess")
        if attack(g,padsel,ct_prev, ct_target):
            m2 += "{:02x}".format(i)
            print(m2)
            break
        else:
            continue   
m2 = m2[::-1] 
print(m2 + "- m2")
```

How do I change the outer loop definition to do this?

Pseudo code:

```
for padsel in pad (items 2-16):
    do stuff until hitting a break condition
else:
    do stuff on element 1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use an else clause on the for loop, just modify the iterable (list) that you iterate over:

```
for padsel in (pad[1:16] + [pad[0]]):
    print(str(hexlify(padsel)) +  "- selected pad")
    for i in range(256):    #increment guess
        g = unhexlify("000000000000000000000000000000" + "{:02x}".format(i)) 
        print(str(hexlify(g)) + "- guess")
        if attack(g,padsel,ct_prev, ct_target):
            m2 += "{:02x}".format(i)
            print(m2)
            break
        else:
            continue   
m2 = m2[::-1] 
print(m2 + "- m2")
```

Using an else clause would require duplication of the code in the body of the for loop, or refactoring the body into a function so that duplication is not required. But, since the first item is processed in the same way as the other items, the simplest way is to organise for it to be processed last by iterating over items 2 through 16 and then item 1 if required.

```
>>> l = range(1,16+1)
>>> print l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
>>> print l[1:16] + [l[0]]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1]
```

The last statement effectively moved the first element of the list to the end of the list. If you don't mind if the list is modified, or even prefer it, you can do this:

```
>>> l = range(1,16+1)
>>> l.append(l.pop(0))
>>> print l
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep original list untouched, try:

```
for item in items[1:16]:  # iterate through elements 1-17 (list indexes starts at 0
    do stuff
    if condition:
        break
else: # else in for loops will be run if loop ended normally (w/o `break`)
    do stuff with items[0]
```

Keep in mind, that slicing lists (list[x:y]) will create a copy of existing list. This can become a memory issue, when used with huge lists.